# JQuery hide scrolls to the top of the page

Tags: jquery

When I call .hide on a div and then .show on another div to replace the last one, the page scrolls to the top. These calls are triggered by a timer. Any idea how to prevent the page from scrolling to the top?

Comment: It would greatly help if you showed your code. Hiding and showing elements won't scroll the page unless they change the size of the page

Comment: Use .scrollTop().
More info [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009029/restoring-page-scroll-position-with-jquery