# Count Descendants of an element

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help write the logic for finding the number of descendants of an element.

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <ul>
          <li><button>item</button></li>
        </ul>
        <p>Hello, world</p>
      </main>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js :

```
  function countDescendants(element) {}

  // Test code
  const result = countDescendants(document.querySelector("main"));
  if (result !== 4) {
    console.error(`fail: ${result}`);
  } else {
    console.log("Pass!");
  }
```

Can some help me to write the countDescendants function.We cant use built in function. should write our own logic. For this particular example it should return the result 4.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the children and descentants, the simplest way to do this is to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) this way:

```
document.querySelectorAll('main *').length
```

**Complete code:**

```js
  // Test code
  const result = document.querySelectorAll("main *").length;
  if (result !== 4) {
    console.log(`fail: ${result}`);
  } else {
    console.log("Pass!");
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <ul>
          <li><button>item</button></li>
        </ul>
        <p>Hello, world</p>
      </main>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to get unique selector for an element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66291608/4592648 Edit: you don't have to, just call querySelectorAll('*') on the node itself

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses the `.children` property of each element and recursively walks the DOM tree, counting children as it goes.

```js
function countDescendants(el) {
  function countChildren({ children }) {
    let count = 0
    if(!children.length) return 0
    for(let el of [...children]) {
      count++
      count += countChildren(el)
    }
    return count
  }
  return countChildren(el)
}
const result = countDescendants(document.querySelector('main'))
console.log(result) // 4
```

```html
<main>
  <ul>
    <li><button>item</button></li>
  </ul>
  <p>Hello, world</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

> The `Element` method `querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) `NodeList` representing a list of elements matching the specified group of selectors which are descendants of the element on which the method was called.

```
function countDescendants(el) {
  return el.querySelectorAll('*').length
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//=======================================================
// If you want to count children of an element

document.querySelector('#total-children').innerText = document.querySelectorAll('#parent > *').length + ' Children';

// or

document.querySelector('#total-children-2').innerText = document.querySelector('#parent').childElementCount + ' Children';

// In you have already selected an element and wants to find his children then you can do this

const elem = document.querySelector('#parent');
document.querySelector('#total-children-3').innerText = elem.querySelectorAll(':scope > *').length + ' Children';

//=======================================================


// If you want to count descendants
document.querySelector('#total-descendants-2').innerText = document.querySelectorAll('#parent *').length + ' Descendants';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <h5>Heading</h5>
    <h6>Heading</h6>
  </div>
  <p id="total-children"></p>
  <p id="total-children-2"></p>
  <p id="total-children-3"></p>
  <p id="total-descendants-2"></p>
</body>
</html>
```