# Can I perform "Copy Selector" with javascript without using Chrome Dev tools

Tags: javascript

Is there a function that gives the dom element to a Javascript function with Javascript and returns the Selector of that element in the relevant html as a string. Briefly, I want to do the process in the picture below without using Chrome dev tools. I looked inside the nodes but couldn't find a breakdown that gives the selector

[image: ChromeDevTools Copy Selector]

Comment: No, I don't think there is a standard JS function which returns a selector for a given element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript get element unique selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184322/javascript-get-element-unique-selector)

Comment: @nullptr the url you posted solved my problem. thank you very much