# html/js: go back to previous page in the same scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's just say I have a page that is quite long, like an article. There's a link like `buy full article now` or something. When clicked it will redirect to a page that contains all my script, add the article to the database, and redirect back again to the article page. Is this possible? and also, how can I make it that it will redirect to same *scroll position* that the user was browsing?

**Good example** of this is like the `BACK` button on the browser. It will take you to the previous page you visited, at the same *scrolling position*

Answer (score 2):

From [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203312/how-can-i-retain-the-scroll-position-of-a-scrollable-area-when-pressing-back-but)

> During page unload, get the scroll position and store it in local
> storage. Then during page load, check local storage and set that
> scroll position. Assuming you have a div element with id element. In
> case it's for the page, please change the selector :)
>
> ```
> $(function() {
>    $(window).unload(function() {
>       var scrollPosition = $("div#element").scrollTop();
>       localStorage.setItem("scrollPosition", scrollPosition);
>    });
>    if(localStorage.scrollPosition) {
>       $("div#element").scrollTop(localStorage.getItem("scrollPosition"));
>    }
> });
> ```

Comment: this will not work actually , if you go from page1 to page 2 it will save the scroll of page1, then if you go page from page2 to page1 it will save again the scroll amount of page 2 before going to page1

Final result : page 1 will scroll to the saved value from page2

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pure Javascript:

```js
window.history.back()
```