# Going back to previous scroll position when clicking the back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, smoothstate.js

how do I go back to my previous scroll position when clicking the back button using the smoothState plugin?

P.S. I'm fairly new when it comes to JS so I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: I believe this has what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203312/how-can-i-retain-the-scroll-position-of-a-scrollable-area-when-pressing-back-but

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I retain the scroll position of a scrollable area when pressing back button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203312/how-can-i-retain-the-scroll-position-of-a-scrollable-area-when-pressing-back-but)

Comment: This doesn't actually work because the page doesn't refresh when clicking the back button but performs an ajax call instead.