# How to use scroll top to trigger an animation in css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm having trouble using scrolltop() function to trigger an animation with css. I want the text **'Scroll down to change effect'** to hide and show the two buttons when the user scroll down to 70 pixels down. But this function does not seem to work. Do I have to use an offset to trigger an animation? Please help, I want to familiarize jquery and animation css.

**Here's my code below:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 70)
      {
        $('.process h2').hide();
        $('.process a').show();

      }
      else {
          $('.process h2').show();
          $('.process a').hide();
      }
    });
```

```css
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {margin: 0;}
    a {text-decoration: none;color: #2aabcc;}
    body {background: #f3f3f3;height: 1200px;}
    .container {width: 1000px;max-width: 100%;position: relative;margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;}
    .page_header {overflow: hidden;}
    .page_header h1 {text-align: center;position: relative;animation: pagetitle 1.5s;}
    .process {text-align: center;padding: 30px 10px;}
    .process a {color: #000;display: inline-block;line-height: 44px;border: 1px solid #000;margin: 0 auto;width: 150px;height: 44px;text-align: center;}
    .process a:hover {color: #b51e1e;border: 1px solid #b51e1e;}
    @keyframes pagetitle {
      0%{transform: translateY(-81%);opacity: 0;}
      50% {opacity: 0.5;}
      100% {transform: translateY(0%);opacity: 1;}
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<div class="container">
<div class="page_header">
<h1>Welcome to Animation Scroll</h1>
</div>
<div class="process">
<h2>Scroll down to change effect</h2>
<a href="#">See our Process</a>
<a href="#">View more</a>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the document to `$(document).scroll()`. Right now you're you're using `$(document).ready()` event, which only declares what should happen when the **document is ready.**  But to declare a set of functions/features for when the document is scrolling(event), you must use the appropriate jQuery event, which in this case is `scroll()`.

```
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
     if ($(document).scrollTop() > 70)
      {
        $('.process h2').hide();
        $('.process a').show();

      }
      else {
          $('.process h2').show();
          $('.process a').hide();
      }
});
```

Comment: this is what I've been looking for, thank you. But I have a question sir, what if the user refreshes the page on the design vertical position which is 50pixels does the effect will still work? Cause I have tried it it will still show the text not the buttons, unless the user will scroll once and it will take effect

Comment: No. The scrolling position is never saved by the browser by default. You can however do it using cookies or localstorage and what not, but that introduces a whole new level of "complexity".  However, if you're interested, here's a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203312/how-can-i-retain-the-scroll-position-of-a-scrollable-area-when-pressing-back-but. Don't forget to mark my answer correct if it helped you. Thanks!