# How to go Back to previus page position in blazor with back button browser?

Tags: scroll, blazor

My web site have 2 page :
1-Index
2-FullNews

On the index page  i have news list that user can click it and then navigate page to FullNews page.
but when user click to browser back button , index page scroll to top page . i want back to previuse current scroll position .

How can i do it?
Tank you

Comment: You need to show us some code?

Comment: Https://Farbuild.ir
This is my web site

Comment: Looks like there are some solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203312/how-can-i-retain-the-scroll-position-of-a-scrollable-area-when-pressing-back-but