# React routing and back button reloading

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-routing, back-button

I'm using React with react-router v4 for routing in a SPA app.

From within a list page, when user taps on an item, we navigate to detail url which renders detail component.

From here, if I click back, route transitions to list page but list page itself is reloaded. So its scroll position, selection of an item (which opened the details page) is lost.

I have been struggling to think about how to approach this problem. One way I was thinking is to build all pages to open as model on top of another so base page context is always there and when user navigates back, I can start to close the modals revealing previous page in its exact state.

Not sure if that is a right approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the current scroll position locally, then scroll back to it when your list page component is mounted.

These are jQuery answers, but the principle is the same:

- [Restoring page scroll position with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009029)
- [How can I retain the scroll position of a scrollable area when pressing back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203312)