# Keep scroll position inside div after reload php file with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div with it's own scroll bar which is being reloaded by AJAX (php file). When I scroll inside this div and reload it, the inner scrollbar gets sent back to the top. I would like for the scroll bar to remain at the position where I originally scrolled to.

```
<style>
    #div2 {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#div1').load('shownic8.php');
    },7000);
</script>
<div id="div1">
</div>
```

Here is the code from "shownic8.php" file

```
<div id="div2">
...
</div>
```

Can you help me keep the position of my scroll bar? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

1. Before `.load()` store current scroll position:

   `var pos = $('#your-container').scrollTop();`
2. Use `.load()` callback (http://api.jquery.com/load/) to restore scroll position:

   `$('#your-container').scrollTop(pos);`

Using your code:

```
        setInterval(function () {
            var scrollTarget = $('#div1');
            var pos = scrollTarget.scrollTop();
            scrollTarget.load('shownic8.php', function() {
                $('#div1').scrollTop(pos);
            });
        },7000);
```

Comment: Your can also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009029/restoring-page-scroll-position-with-jquery

Comment: I changed in style "div1" instead of "div2"  and  it works fine :) Thank you.

Comment: Glad can help. Please note that this way of loading data with frequent refresh will have some side effects that has been pointed by @bitifet.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use DOM element's `scrollTop` property or jQuery function of the same name.

But I don't advice you to do so because saving and restoring scroll position you couldn't avoid a slight blinking effect every time you reload contents.

So, instead, I would recommend to update items that actually change instead of reloading the whole contents, so the scrollTop property gets never changed.

Of course, (to do it the right way) it implies modifying your `shownic8.php` page (or implementing another different route instead) to return some structured data and use them to fill or update your div contents.

On the other hand, you can try another, slightly dirty, approach to *hide* that blinking efect (replacing it by a less obvious side effect). That is:

1. Instead of loading your contents directly into `#div1` element, create a new div inside it (appending through `.append()` or `.appendTo()`) and load into it.
2. After that (at least in reloading operations), remove previous contents so that new content climbs up to the top position (and not altering scroll position).

**Example:** (untested)

```
setInterval(function () {
    var prevContents = $("#div1>*");
    $('<div></div>')
        .load('shownic8.php')
        .appendTo('#div1')
    ;
    prevContents.remove();
},7000);
```